# How to Execute linux bash command from Wine

Tags: notepad++, wine

I am using Notepad++ with plugin `NPPExec` for running Perl scripts on MS windows.

like:

```
cmd/c perl script.pl arg1 arg2
```

Is it possible to do the same using wine on Linux calling the native Perl interpreter.

I tried the below link it seems it only works for GUI applications.

[7.5 How do I associate a native program with a file type in Wine?](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-bc5b677c29daa2cd16b83bca8c88f31b2341cb98)

For command line output (console ouput) I am getting below error 
like:

```
fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnOnViewWindowActive stub, 0x1387b8 (0x155a78)
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x0000000c
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I don't use "Notepad++", but do succeed with "Source Insight (wine on Linux)", by using path like "Z:\usr\bin\perl", if perl is at "/usr/bin/perl"

Answer (score 0):

This should work by setting the command to  `start /unix /usr/bin/perl winepath arg1`

if you have more complicated arguments it might be best to create a bash script and call it with all the arguments and do the parsing there.

(I know the question is very old, it was still a question for me)